# How to avoid getting email Content analysis details and get only Message content in email Piped

Tags: php, email, pipe

I am writing a PHP script to get email piped to the script and save it to the database.. I have succeeded in get coming emails.. But i am still struggling with how to get rid of raw contents that comes with the email.. What technique can i use to get only the message either the text version or the html version
This is the example of email i receive currently

```js
Content preview:  Mine Mine [...]

 Content analysis details:   (-0.1 points, 5.0 required)

  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 -0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
  0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider
                             (techservice4real[at]gmail.com)
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                             domain
  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
 -0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 -0.0 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2      RBL: Average reputation (+2)
                             [209.85.222.182 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
X-Spam-Flag: NO

--000000000000c1a52105822cd389
Content-Type: text/plain; charset='UTF-8'

Mine

--000000000000c1a52105822cd389
Content-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'

<div dir='ltr'>Mine<br></div>

--000000000000c1a52105822cd389--
```

This is currently the code i am using to get the email

```js
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php 
require_once('inc/init.php');   
//chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
// if(strlen($email)<1) {
//     die(); 
// }
// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);
// empty vars
$from = "";
$to="";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$bodyContent = "";
$myBody = "";
$splittingheaders = true;
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}

$data = explode("\n", $message);
mail("boomztechs@gmail.com", "You Have One new Email Piped", "A New Mail Message just Piped to you) ".$message);
```

Your response is highly appreciated thanks..

Comment: Your example is missing the headers, which is an important part as they define the MIME boundary. The you use the boundary to parse the message into parts, each of which have their own headers. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html Unfortunately PHP doesn't have a userland function for parsing multipart, but there are a [few libs available].

Comment: Hi Sammitch, Thank you for your response.. Please i want you to explain futher to me i don't understand what you mean by " Example is missing Headers".. Are you talking about the code or the email sample?

Comment: Your sample email has its headers removed. Assuming that this is a pipe milter you've either cut them off for privacy/brevity, or your milter is being fed incomplete messages. You need the `boundary` property from the message's `Content-Type:` header in order to properly parse the message into parts. While it might _look_ obvious for this particular message you should not be trying to guess it.

Comment: Yes, I did not border to copy the Header part of the email.. I get all the other path like. Email From, Email To, Subject.. It is only the body that i am having issue with.. That is why i copy the body sample.. My question is how can i get rid of all those raw data before and after both the text and html version of the email.. I want to be able to get only the message.. How can i do this with php? Thanks